# Grabbing Spotify playlist of an authenticated user

Tags: php, web, spotify

I want to grab users playlist and inbox. for an authenticated my app on spotify. same like we grab data from facebook api.

Thanks

EDIT: i found only tried https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/ but this provides only lookup and searcg for tracks, albums etc, not for the playlist from a specific user,

Comment: This reads more like a specification than a question.  What have you tried?  What specific problems have you had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spotify Apps API doesn't provide direct access to user playlists for privacy reasons.

However, if you allow users do drop playlists onto your application, you can get at them that way.

Answer (score 0):

The playlists can be accessed through spotify APIs

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/playlists/

You need however user authorization to access private playlist.